# Is a request for photographic evidence (ID & credit card) legitimate for the purchase of tickets to the Australian Open?

Tags: tickets, australia, scams

Next month I'm going to Australia for the first time and will visit the Australian Open in Melbourne. Yesterday I bought the tickets for AO by [Ticketbis](http://www.ticketbis.com/en/search/index?q=Australian%20open) and today received an mail requiring me to send my private data to this company (photograph of my ID and credit card). This is an unusual situation for me, I have never got such mails before (already bought tickets in Europe and Canada).

What should I do? Does anybody here have experience of this company or of buying tickets for AO? Is Ticketbis reputable?

I'm afraid of internet thieves. I have to answer this mail during the next 24 hours.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not exactly unusual, it's a credit card problem and it happens everywhere not just Australia and all the time, I myself have been getting these emails for more than two decades. Recent sample (this was from a Chinese shop, needless to say I rather shopped elsewhere):

[image]

Comment: This is exactly the text, which I have got in my mail. Thank you

Comment: What I usually do is black out the sensitive parts of my passport, so that it's unusable for fraud. The shop doesn't really need those anyway.

Comment: I never sign my credit cards, but rather write "See ID" which causes the vendor to ask for my photo ID (driver's license) (in the US) ... I wonder at the issue that might raise for this